# Does xpath nodeset contain another

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I have two variables in my xslt 1.0 template, each one holding a node-set (selected with xpath). I want to determine if the node set in one variable is contained in the node set in the other. For example, suppose I have a chapter with nested sections. I want to see if `$b` is contained in `$a`:

```
<xsl:variable name="a" select="chapter//section" />
<xsl:variable name="b" select="chapter//section" />
```

I've tried to get an intersection of the nodesets to see if `$a` is the first common element shared by both `$a` and `$b` but this is not working:

```
<xsl:if test="$a/ancestor-or-self::*[count(.|$b) = count($b/ancestor::*)][1] = $a">
```

Adding some context. I'm creating a tabbed interface for a tree of html pages with this xslt, and the problem I'm trying to solve is to put class="current" on the proper tab. By testing each section to see if it is a child of the tab section, it gets the class="current" and so the tab will be styled to look as if it is on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Michael Kay's good answer:

**When a node `$n` belongs to a node-set `$ns`**?

If a node belongs to a node-set then the union of the node with the node-set doesn't result in a bigger node-set -- so the number of the nodes in the union must not be greater (in fact must be equal to) than the number of nodes in the original nodeset.

**To express this with an XPath expression**:

```
 count($n | $ns) = count($ns)
```

**Now, the same logic tells us that a nodeset `$ns1` is a subset of a nodeset `$ns2`** exactly when the union of the two node-sets doesn't contain more elements that the bigger node-set:

```
count($ns1 | $ns2) = count($ns2)
```

**If we want to test if `$ns1` is a *true* subset of `$ns2`**:

```
    count($ns1 | $ns2) = count($ns2)
   and
    count($ns2) > count(ns1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can simply use `count($a) = count($a|$b)`. If there are any nodes in $b that are not in $a, the counts will be different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added some context to the question since it is hard for me to explain. If I only count nodes, it seems to me that the following would cause confusion since each parent has the same number of node children. Am I misunderstanding?   <chapter>
  <section><title>Section A</title>
     <section><title>Section A.1</title>
     </section>
  </section>
  <section><title>Section B</title>
     <section><title>Section B.1</title>
     </section>
  </section>
</chapter>

Comment: @Tim: Your main problem is that you didn't try the XPath expression in the answer -- if you had done that, you wouldn't be asking such questions in the comments. The expression in this answer is the most direct (and shortest) way to test for node-set inclusion. You are trying to find other ways and they may work in one situation but not in another -- this may not be the most useful way to spend your time. For more information read here: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9944e108 . +1 from me.

Comment: @Dimitre, I didn't *understand* the answer. Thanks to you and Michael I now see that `|` is a union operator and I thought it was just a logical `or`. I've upvoted Michael's answer and accepted yours. I'm learning. For my particular situation I think my solution is fine, but it is not the answer to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem using a different method. I test each ancestor element of `$b` to see whether it has the same xml:id as `$a`:

```
<xsl:if test="boolean($b/ancestor-or-self::[@xml:id=$a/@xml:id])">
```

While this is not using an intersection, it does tell whether `$a` contains `$b`.